# .NET Core: Why are so many threads when I use async IO (OS Windows)?

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, .net-core, task

I am a little bit confused about how many threads .net core creates. I have a very simple program that fetch static contnet from our application`s server by array of urls:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(10, 10);

        var urls = new string[]
        {
            "http://url1.....",
            "http://url2.....",
            .......
        };

        var taskCount = 100;
        var count = 1000;
        var httpClient = new HttpClient {Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000)};
        var tasks = new Collection<Task>();
        var threads = new ConcurrentBag<int>();

        for (var i = 0; i < taskCount; i++)
        {
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                var sw = new Stopwatch();

                for (var j = 0; j < count; j++)
                {
                    foreach (var url in urls)
                    {
                        sw.Start();

                        try
                        {
                            threads.Add(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

                            using (var r = await httpClient.GetAsync(url))
                            {
                                threads.Add(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

                                if (r.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                                {
                                    sw.Stop();

                                    Console.WriteLine($"[{url}] - status: [{r.StatusCode}], time: [{sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}]");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    using (var content = r.Content)
                                    {
                                        threads.Add(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

                                        _ = await content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

                                        threads.Add(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

                                        sw.Stop();

                                        Console.WriteLine($"[{url}] - status: [{r.StatusCode}], time: [{sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}]");
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(e);
                        }

                        sw.Reset();
                    }
                }
            }));
        }

        Console.ReadKey();

        File.AppendAllText(@"E:\temp\log.txt", $"t count: {threads.ToList().Distinct().ToList().Count}\r\n");
    }
}
```

Only 100 tasks fetch content by urls, log this and do it again. When I run this program on OS Windows by using .NET Core 2.0, I see 10 threads in log file. I understand that these are threads from the thread pool, but when I look on count of threads in Windows Resource Monitor, I see 120 threads. Why?
If I run this program on OS Windows by using .NET Framework 4.7.1, I see 17 threads in log file and 37 threads in Windows Resource Monitor. If I use ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(10, 10) for both cases, nothing changes, I still see 120 threads in .NET Core 2.0 and around 37 threads in .NET Framework 4.7.1 by looking on Windows Resource Monitor. I do not understand why. Please, someone explain to me what are these 120 threads and why does .NET Core 2.0 create them so much?

Comment: Thread in .Net is NOT a thread in OS - it is an abstraction to run the work. It's up to system how many threads to create.

Comment: This is not an answer for my question because I see 120 native OS threads in the Windows Resource Monitor for this process. I create only 100 tasks which must be executed in thread pool and thread pool have less threads than I can see in the Windows Resource Monitor.